# get adjacent rows that match a condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks as follows.

```
    Datetime                  Message                           Prediction

0   2021-12-20 09:50:08.819   Current sidewing pressure: 3362   1
1   2021-12-20 09:50:08.820   Current sidewing pressure: 3303   1  
2   2021-12-20 09:50:08.839   Current sidewing pressure: 3398   -1
3   2021-12-20 09:50:08.839   Current sidewing pressure: 3279   -1   
4   2021-12-20 09:50:08.860   Current sidewing pressure: 3398   -1
5   2021-12-20 09:50:08.860   Current sidewing pressure: 3303   -1   
6   2021-12-20 09:50:08.879   Current sidewing pressure: 3303   1
```

And I want to make a dataframe from rows that are adjacent and have the same prediction value, in this example get 3 new dataframes.

Is there any way I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the dataframe on `Prediction` change using `numpy.split`:

```
import numpy as np
dfs = np.split(df, np.flatnonzero(df.Prediction.diff().fillna(0).ne(0)))

dfs[0]
                  Datetime                          Message  Prediction
0  2021-12-20 09:50:08.819  Current sidewing pressure: 3362           1
1  2021-12-20 09:50:08.820  Current sidewing pressure: 3303           1

dfs[1]
                  Datetime                          Message  Prediction
2  2021-12-20 09:50:08.839  Current sidewing pressure: 3398          -1
3  2021-12-20 09:50:08.839  Current sidewing pressure: 3279          -1
4  2021-12-20 09:50:08.860  Current sidewing pressure: 3398          -1
5  2021-12-20 09:50:08.860  Current sidewing pressure: 3303          -1

dfs[2]
                  Datetime                          Message  Prediction
6  2021-12-20 09:50:08.879  Current sidewing pressure: 3303           1
```